# Grouping photos with application machine tags vs. security

Tags: php, flickr

I am wondering how should I group my photos inside Flick to be able to read later by API and assign them to a event. So an event should have X photos assigned.

Initially thought that I will organize in Galleries but that has a limit of photos. Next was to organize in Sets, but I couldn't locate if a Set has a limit.

Then I've read about [namespace:predicate=value](http://www.flickr.com/help/tags/) functionality. This is something which could come handy as I can define unique value for each event.

But I have a questions relative to security?
1. Can I define a unique tag per user/application? Can we subscribe to a unique tag per app?
2. Are my tags publicly viewable by the user?
3. Can in the future someone else attach my specific tags to different photos and so SPAM my photo gallery read out by API?
4. Can I exclude some 3rd party photos from the tagging mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the easiest way to do this would be the use the app name as the namespace, e.g. app1:predicate=value, app2:predicate=value
2. Yes, if the photo is public then you can also see the machine tags associated with it.
3. Anyone can apply a particular tag to their photos. However, you can restrict the API query for all photos with a particular tag so that only photos by a given user are returned, which would stop people spamming your gallery.
4. If you want to exclude photos from other users from the tagging mechanism, you can either only request photos with a given tag from a given user (this is possible with the API call), or you could moderate each photo so that it only shows up in your gallery once you've checked it (e.g. keep a database table with the photo ID and an approved flag for each photo).